# why non english letter render gibberish in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am defining a element in html

```
<pre id="dict"></pre>
```

and I am setting the inner html like this

```
document.getElementById("dict").innerHTML=<p>ಒಂದ್</p>;
```

but the render is gibberish

```
à²’à²‚à²¦à³
```

expected result

```
ಒಂದ್
```

what am i missing here?

Comment: What is the character set of the page? It has to be UTF-8 to work properly.

Comment: My gibberish-detector is telling me something something windows-1252

Comment: that was a simple fix, thanks for your time @Pointy

Comment: no it wasnt explicitly set @ASDFGerte

Comment: It's just that for reasons i've rather not have had, my eyes recently looked at so much "utf-8 being read as windows-1252", that the gibberish looked almost normal for me. Unsure, if there are other encoding changes causing the same result, but if you check utf-8 ಒಂದ್ mistakenly read as windows-1252 e.g. [here](http://string-functions.com/encodedecode.aspx), you'll see your example gibberish.

Comment: as the docs stated UTF-8 is default character encoding i didnt set it explicitly, should i remove the question?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, please try the below snippet.

```js
$("#dict").html("<p>ಒಂದ್</p>")
var value = $("#dict").text();
alert(value)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<pre id="dict"></pre>
```